# Rewriting static page to page with parameter in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have read here for hours on the removal of parameters with a 301 forwarding in the htaccess.

I have unfortunately the exact opposite:
I want to redirect a static page to a dynamic with parameter.

example:

Www.example.com/123 => www.example.com/123/?search=parameter1&parameter2

I have tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
    RewriteEngine On    
    RewriteBase /    
    Redirect 301 /almhuetten-in-alleinlage-mieten/      https://example.com/almhuetten-in-alleinlage-mieten/?search=&from=&weeks=1&persons=1&countries=Alle&item%5B%5D=H%C3%BCtte+befindet+sich+in+Alleinlage    
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]    
</IfModule>
```

Unfortunately I get the error too many redirects.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How will it rewrite to the query perameters if your requested uri is **/123** . Please post a clear example of your urls.

Comment: You are getting a redirect loop error because you are mapping **/123** to  **/123** (same location) . You cant avoid this unless you use mod-rewrite.

Comment: i have edited the complete code - mod_rewrite is active.  so can i not redirect to the same directory, although afterwards still come parameters?